# To check the range of given number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to check the number is in range of 1 to 100, 100 to 200 and so on but without using if conditions.
if it is in range of 1 to 100 return 100.

Comment: will the user give 2 inputs? 
what is that you want the function to do?

Comment: no we have only one number we have to detect it is in range of 1 to 100 or 100  to 200 and so on.

Comment: and return what the maximum of the range correct?

Answer (score 7):

If the type is int

For 1-100,101-200,

```
 int x = 99;
 x = ((x-1)/100 + 1)*100;
```

For 1-50,51-100

```
int x= 51;
x = ((x-1)/50 + 1)*50;
```

Comment: The cast is not necessary.

Comment: I am not sure if the original number is int or not.Just in case

Comment: An division of to int operands is an int division,which has an int result.

Comment: When you remove the cast, I would up vote your answer. ;-)

Comment: BTW if the input is a floating point number, your answer doesn't work, i. e. for 100.3. This is because you rely on the discreteness of integers at `-1`.

Comment: @Leo now if i want the range should be 1 to 50, 50 to 100 and so on then what modification is required

Comment: @SukhmeetHora Does the number is int or float?

Comment: ohh correct I didn't see it can be generalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

/* we need to get 700 in result */

NSInteger myNumber = 619;

/* outputNumber will give 700 in result */

NSInteger outputNumber = (NSInteger)(ceil(myNumber/100) * 100);

Comment: `ceil()` is for `double`, returns a `double` and has no meaning here.

Comment: added (NSInteger) for typecasting and earlier it was doing implicit conversion

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following function

```
-(int)getOutput:(int)input{
int temp = (input+99)/100;  //(eg :- temp=(99+99)/100=1;

int output=temp*100  //(eg :- 1*100 =100);
return output;
}
```

Comment: This will return 200 for 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (int)getRange:(int)value
{
    int range = value / 100;
    range = (range * 100) + ((value % 100) > 0 ? 100 : 0);
    return range;
}
```

Try this hope it ll help you..

Comment: This returns 200 for 100.

Comment: The parenthesis in the second expression are meaningless.